# using quotes and other special characters on cmd command line

Tags: cmd, escaping

I often use command line tools and from time to time i struggle with the interpreters interpretation of argument boundaries then using quotes.

example:

```
grep -r "#include"  . | perl -pe "s/.*?#include.*?[\"<](.*?)[\">].*/\1/"
```

I want to extract a list of all includes from all the files in the subdirectories. The problem seems to be that the cmd only accept double quotes. since they are also part of the regular expression i have to escape them there. But this seems not to work. the inpterpreter complains about invalid filename schemes (since it misinterprets the angular bracket as input redirection operator). using back slashes seems not to work.

Does anybody has some advise/tip/help for me how to work around this? (beside installing alternative shells)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**. Next command line sample could enlighten it a bit more (`echo` returns the same string you provided in your question):

```
==>echo "s/.*?#include.*?[\"^<](.*?)[\">].*/\1/"
"s/.*?#include.*?[\"<](.*?)[\">].*/\1/"
```

> All theory, dear friend, is gray, but the golden tree of life springs ever green. (*Johann Wolfgang von Goethe*)

`"inner ^"double^" quotes"` **should** result to *inner "double" quotes* (but do not). For instance, in plain `"s/.*?#include.*?[\"<](.*?)[\">].*/\1/"` supplied as a parameter there are three "tokens" parsed:

- `"s/.*?#include.*?[\"`
- `<](.*?)[\`
- `">].*/\1/"`

Next command  with `<` escaped in middle "token" (which isn't surrouded by double quotes) *should* work as expected in a batch script as well as in bare command line.

```
perl -pe "s/.*?#include.*?[\"^<](.*?)[\">].*/\1/"
```

Read [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html). In next batch (`.bat`) script you could see some examples:

```
@setlocal
@Echo ^@  - At Symbol: be less verbose
@Echo ^~  - Tilde: Parameter Expansion as in Call subroutines, FOR loops etc.
@Echo ^&  - Single Ampersand: used as a command separator
@Echo ^&^& - Double Ampersand: conditional command separator (if errorlevel 0)
@Echo ^|^| - Double Pipe: conditional command separator (if errorlevel ^> 0)
@Echo ^:^: - Double Colon: alternative to "rem" for comments outside of code blocks
@Echo ^^  - Caret: general escape character in batch
@Echo ^"  - Double Quote: surrounding a string in double quotes 
@Echo      escapes all of the characters contained within it
@Echo ^() - Parentheses: used to make "code blocks" of grouped commands
@Echo %%  - Percentage Sign: are used to mark three of the four variable types
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@Echo ^^!  - Exclamation Mark: to mark delayed expansion environment variables ^^!var^^!
@endlocal
@setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
@Echo ^!  - Exclamation Mark: to mark delayed expansion environment variables ^!var^!
@endlocal
@Echo ^*  - Asterisk: wildcard matches any number or any characters
@Echo ^?  - Question Mark: matches any single character
@Echo ^.  - Single dot: represents the current directory
@Echo ^.. - Double dot: represents the parent directory of the current directory
@Echo ^\  - Backslash: represent the root directory of a drive dir ^\
@Echo ^|  - Single Pipe: redirects the std.output of one command
@Echo      into the std.input of another
@Echo ^NUL (File like device): is like a bottomless pit
@Echo ^CON (File like device): is a file like device that represents the console
@Echo ^>  - Single Greater Than: redirects output to either a file or file like device
@Echo ^>^> - Double Greater than: output will be added to the very end of the file
@Echo ^<  - Less Than: redirect the contents of a file to the std.input of a command
@Echo      Stream redirection: regarding the less and greater than symbols
@Echo      "http://judago.webs.com/batchoperators.htm"
@endlocal
@rem pause
@GOTO :eof
```

Comment: this may apply (havn't tested) to batches but does not seem to have any influence to normal command lines

Comment: thanks for the update - it seems to work. that does mean that the double quotes does not have to be escaped at all (the back slash in the rectangular brackets does not belong to the expression)? but if they have not to be escaped - why the parser interprets the '<' as redirection operator? - i am more confused about the argument parser than before. the site you linked does not cover the presence of quotes in the parameter.